# Como remover o nome do usuário do OS

Tags: python, sistema-operacional

Estou fazendo um terminal e estou com uma duvida,
como faço pra remover o nome do usuário para atrás da mensagem?

```
exemplo: "C:/USERS/GUSTAVO/DESKTOP"
```

Como faço para deixar:

> exemplo: "DESKTOP"

Estou usando a biblioteca OS para pegar o diretório.

Código:

```
import so
import sys
import platform
diretorio = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(diretorio)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o `strip` juntamente com `getuser`

```py
import os
import sys
import platform
from getpass import getuser
diretorio = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).strip(getuser())
print(diretorio)
```

Comment: Não resultou amigo...

Comment: você quer deixar a ultima pasta na variavel diretorio? acho que não entendi direito

Comment: Sim, por como você pode ver o exemplo, tem outras pastas ( usuarios,gustavo ) porem quero somente deixar o nome da pasta "Desktop" para frente.

Comment: "C:/USERS/GUSTAVO/DESKTOP" isso ficaria assim "C:/USERS/DESKTOP"?

Comment: Isso mesmo, aguardo resposta <3

Comment: Resolvido, esse codigo que você atualizou, porem você não me avisou resolveu o poblema. Obrigado! +1